# Need SQL MAX please

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a list of Client No's, ID etc & there are many Clients with different ID's.  I need to pull out the MAX ID No. for each Client, e.g.

ClientNo: 1500   has 3 ID's -  the maximum in the ID field is the one I need!

UPDATE:  This works:

```
SELECT MP.ClientID, MP.SequenceID
FROM  TABLENAME MP
INNER JOIN (
SELECT ClientID, MAX(SequenceID) SequenceID
FROM  TABLENAME
GROUP BY ClientID
) b on MP.ClientID = b.ClientID AND MP.SequenceID = b.SequenceID
```

BUT....

I need to link the table to many others to pull in other data, where do I insert the left joins to these tables please?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have multiple same client (numbers) with different IDs and for each client (number) you have to get the maximum ID. You may do the following:

```
select client_number, max(ID) from client group by client_number;
```

Depending on your need tweak this query.

Comment: SELECT MP.ClientID, MP.SequenceID
FROM  [5QDC_BAK].[dbo].[MonthlyPlannerApp] MP
INNER JOIN (
SELECT ClientID, MAX(SequenceID) SequenceID
FROM  [5QDC_BAK].[dbo].[MonthlyPlannerApp]

GROUP BY ClientID
) b on MP.ClientID = b.ClientID AND MP.SequenceID = b.SequenceID

Comment: but I need to insert some left joins to other tables do you know where I need to do this please?

Comment: After you finished your inner join, start the left outer join assuming that the left side is the primary side. It looks like: `select a.x, a.y from a inner join b on a.id=b.id left outer join c on a.id=c.id;`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do this:

```
SELECT MP.ClientID, b.DesiredValue
FROM  TABLENAME MP
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ClientID, DesiredValue, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID order by SequenceID desc) As RecentRN
            FROM  TABLENAME
            ) b 
        on MP.ClientID = b.ClientID AND b.RecentRN = 1
```

or

```
SELECT MP.ClientID, b.DesiredValue
FROM  TABLENAME MP
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ClientID, DesiredValue,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID order by SequenceID desc) As RecentRN
            FROM  TABLENAME
            ) b 
        on MP.ClientID = b.ClientID
Where b.RecentRN = 1
```